# Can I reinforce good patterns recognition in LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, lstm

People talking of LSTMs predicting next time step. Which means it should recognise a pattern to make a prediction. Let say it often saw 1 2 3 sequences during learning phase. So when it sees 1 2 it will predict 3. Right?

But what if I don't want to predict the number? What if I need an LSTM to recognise a pattern which cannot be simply quantified?

Here is an example. Waves. You are an LSTM and you are on a beach (nice!). You counting waves. Your inputs are 3d vectors. Each observation is {height,speed,time} (time is count of seconds since previous observation - this is important as waves come at variable intervals). But you see the waves 100 m off the beach. And you stand 10 m off the water edge.

I want you to recognise waves pattern which will result in your feet wet by a wave sequence .

So this question has 2 distinct challenges.

One is "imminence"  - as the waves has different speed it's not possible to know how long would take for a wave to reach your feet. And different patterns will do it in different time. So distance between time step M when LSTM recognised a good pattern and time step N when the it reaches your feet will wary for each good pattern.

Second the output (say I want 0 or 1) is not in the input sequence. It's not predicting next wave it is predicting 0/1.

Can anyone suggest a high level architecture of such LSTM? How can I program "wet feet"? In batch ML it would be called supervised and I would label certain data points with "wet feet" label.

Here is another consideration. Perhaps it should be stacked. Say 3 LSTMs. As some waves will contribute significantly to the wet feet event and some not so. I am thinking may be I need 1 machine to learn small patterns and 2 machine to learn patterns of patterns and 3 machine to actually predict wet feet from it..

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py  for an example of using LSTM for a classification task. The most basic architecture is just a single LSTM layer followed by a single output node:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: thank you. but how do I tell that I want to output 0 and 1, and most importantly what they are (the 0 and the 1) ?

Comment: just feed the 0s and 1s in as the targets in the training data, you'll have to keep track of what the labels mean yourself.